# EditText inside alertdialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

Having this class code to create a dialog :

```
           public class DConce extends DialogFragment{

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dshow = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    dshow.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null))

           .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   //TODO


               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   DConce.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      

    return dshow.create();

    }

           public static DConce newInstance(){
           DConce arg = new DConce();
           return arg;
            }
```

I am trying to get some data from user input with a EditText. The object is created on the xml. I am trying to call it with

```
EditText dlgText = (EditText) Dconce.findViewById(R.id.txconc);
```

But it just will not find findViewByid on the dialog. Isn´t the view included here? 
    dshow.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null))

Any help please? Thanks in advance.

PS: The dialog is created just fine and I can see the EditText. I just cannot work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inflated my view in dialog a bit modified and it worked, like this:

```
LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View editTextLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null);
        EditText dlgText = (EditText ) editTextLayout .findViewById(R.id.txconc);
```

Works for me:

```
public class DConce extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dshow = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View editTextLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext_layout, null);


    dshow.setView(editTextLayout)

           .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   EditText dlgText = (EditText)editTextLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                   String string = dlgText.getText().toString();
                   Log.d("sadsad", string);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   DConce.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      

    return dshow.create();

    }

           public static DConce newInstance(){
               DConce arg = new DConce();
           return arg;
            }
}
```

Call in activity:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
                DialogFragment Dialog = DConce.newInstance();
                Dialog.show(manager, "tag");
```

Comment: Ok, seems to work. However, seems I cannot get the text from it.        @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    
                String Cvar = dlgText.getText().toString();
                 
                 System.out.println("edittext" + Cvar );
                 
                }  It just gives me an empty value.

Comment: are you sure? I just tried it with Log.d and i got input, i will copy paste you my code so try it again pls

Comment: yeah my bad. I forgot to delete this line --- dshow.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null)) . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `EditText dlgText = (EditText) dshow.findViewById(R.id.txconc);`

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
        editalert.setTitle("My Title");
        final EditText input = new EditText(ActivityName.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        editalert.setView(input);
        editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

           String name= input.getText().toString();

            }
        });

        editalert.show();
```

You can also have dialog with custom layout

Your dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ok"
    android:text="CANCEL" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

In your Main Activity

```
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showpopup();
        }

    });
}
public void showpopup()
{
final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setTitle("my title");
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
// Thank you Button Listener. On Click Goes to Home Screen
 Button ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.ok);
final EditText ed= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s= ed.getText().toString();

    }

});
 Button cancel = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d.cancel();

        }

    });
    d.show();

}
```